# Why do we need a webserver even if you want to view the website on your local computer?

Tags: tomcat, iis, webserver

I understand that part of a web server's job is to be able to make it accessible to people outside of your network. So you get a (physical/hardware)server which has some IP, and put the source files of the website in a particular folder on this computer. The web server which is running on this computer, knows how to "cater to" a request it receives from a client. As in, it knows which directory to look for, which in linux, is /var/www and picks up the default file which is index.html

However, this is okay if you want to access the files(basically) from a computer outside yours. But if you just want to see these files from within on your computer, why do you still need a web server?

Why do back-end languages like php, Node.JS etc necessitate the need to have a web server?

Answer (score 2):

To view a static HTML file, you don't need a web server - the browser can simply load the file from disk and display it:

```
file:///home/user/test.html
```

However, more often than not, the HTML needs to be dynamically generated. For example, the website may need you to log in, and then present you with different content to someone else.

This logic needs to run somewhere, and for web pages, it runs in a web server (something that understands the HTTP protocol, which is how browsers make their requests for data).

As an example, consider an email site like Gmail, where you want to view your inbox within a browser. You *could* have a process running on your computer that constantly polls your inbox, and creates a set of static files containing your inbox, and all of its emails. You wouldn't be able to use this to create a new email though - it would just be a very inefficient way of providing a read only view of your mails.

Alternatively, you can use a web server that receives a request from your browser, and at that point it goes and fetches your mail and dynamically generates the HTML needed to display your inbox, and then returns this HTML to the browser for display.

Comment: Imagine I'm the developer of gmail and also the only gmail user. Which means, gmail's sql database is also residing on my system. Also let's leave the web/browser for now and think gmail is a small python program run from the terminal which just queries the DB and prints results to a terminal. Why does the browser version of the same have to be run from inside a web server. What is it that the browser is adding? A web server's job is to route requests form client to server. In this case, no routing is required since client and server are on same system. And so, no web sever is required?

Comment: A browser is incapable of running a Python program - all it knows how to do is fetch and render HTML and run JavaScript (huge oversimplification), and it does this within a sandbox for security reasons, so that it cannot read your bank account details and post them off elsewhere. Therefore, it needs to ask something else to do things like run SQL queries for it, which is where the web server comes in. A web server doesn't route requests, it handles them and responds to them (possibly invoking something like PHP to help it out).

Comment: Just had a silly thought - when you talk about a web server, you don't mean a physically separate machine do you? You can run a web server (e.g. Apache) locally on the same machine as the browser, and use `http://localhost/` to access it.